# .m2 configuration on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have Apache Maven 3 installed in my C: drive and the `settings.xml` file is located in `C:\users\jsmith\.m2\settings.xml`. When I run `mvn clean install` for a project all the required dependencies are downloaded and stored in `C:\users\jsmith\.m2\repository` folder.

However, I also have Jenkins war deployed in Tomcat 8 and when I do the build using Jenkins all the required dependencies are download and stored directly under `C:\.m2` folder (created automatically by Jenkins) instead of `C:\users\jsmith\.m2`.

How can I point my Jenkins to `C:\users\jsmith\.m2` folder so that I do not have two different `.m2` folders created at two different places?

Just and FYI - In Jenkins under the project build configuration and in the Advanced section,I already have the following settings:

```
Settings file: Use default maven settings
Global settings file: Use default maven global settings
```